# Calling .on() before .emit() in event emitter -- is there a timing issue?

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

Take this code, where `f` is a stream that has an event 'body', which calls the listeners with a `m` -- which is itself a stream emitting events:

```
f.on('message', function(m) {
  m.on('body', function(stream, info) {
    var b = '';
    stream.on('data', function(d) {
      b += d;
    });
    stream.on('end', function() {
      if (/^header/i.test(info.which))
        msg.header = Imap.parseHeader(b);
      else
        msg.body = b;
    });
  });
  m.on('attributes', function(attrs) {
    msg.attrs = attrs;
    msg.contentType = partID[1];
  });
});
f.on('end', function() {
  if (hadErr)
    return;
  cb(undefined, msg);
});
```

The backend is emitting a 'message' event, passing it a `m` object. The code then listens to the events `body` and `attributes`. It's all straightforward except that my little brain is in a bit of a crisis (I am not used to dealing with streams). Especially: how is the backend emitting from the `f` and `m` objects, to guarantee that events are indeed called at the right time?

Specifically:

- How would `f` have to be coded, in general terms, in order to make sure that `m`m doesn't emit till `m.on('body', function(stream, info) {` is called?
- Does a listener need to be added with on() *before* the event is emitted in order for it to be caught?
- If so, does that mean that `f` and `m` will emit events *after* the code here has registered?
- If the backend is supposed to guarantee that `b.emit('end')` is called *after* m.emit('end'), how is that even supposed to happen really, still guaranteeing that `on()` is called `before` any one of the events are emitted?

OK I am 100% confused about this matter. I am obviously missing something basic and crucial, and I am not even able to ask the right questions because of this...! (Apologies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does a listener need to be added with on() before the event is emitted in order for it to be caught?

Yes.

> If so, does that mean that f and m will emit events after the code here has registered?

No, events are not queued anywhere.  If nothing is listening for them, they will be lost.  I think that's what you're asking anyway... `f` and `m` don't seem to emit events in your code.

> If the backend is supposed to guarantee that b.emit('end') is called after m.emit('end'), how is that even supposed to happen really, still guaranteeing that on() is called before any one of the events are emitted?

`b` is a string in your example?  I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Think of it differently.  When `.on` is called, a function is subscribed to a channel of messages.  Those messages are already flowing before that function is subscribed, and will continue to flow if that function is unsubscribed.  `.on` and `.removeListener()` just set the subscription status for a particular function.

Events can be emitted even if nothing is listening for them.  Events can fire all the time and if nothing is listening, they just don't go anywhere.  (An exception to this are the error events built into Node.js, which are turned into real exceptions if there isn't an error handler.)

> How would f have to be coded, in general terms, in order to make sure that mm doesn't emit till m.on('body', function(stream, info) { is called?

I still don't follow specifically what you're asking, since none of the code you show emits anything.  But, you wouldn't really want to do this.  You need to be setting up your event handlers before opening a stream, or doing whatever you are doing that causes the events to be fired.

You might be getting confused on the ordering of event handling on new objects.  In Node.js, there is a rule...  Never emit directly from your constructor.  Always use `nextTick()` or similar.  This way, after instantiation, any code to attach itself to event handlers can do so before the events are emitted.

Also, if you are using streams, consider using the `readable` event so that the stream remains paused until you're ready to read from it.  Pull vs. push.

Comment: Thanks Brad! Making sense of it all... I added a question! I think I am narrowing down where my confusion is! The question: `How would f have to be coded, in general terms, in order to make sure that mm doesn't emit till m.on('body', function(stream, info) { is called?` (But please update your answer rather than answering here, I want to accept your response as an answer!)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question. But it's about an issue that still exists, and the answer is subtle and annoying, so I wanted to give it a good answer.

> how is the backend emitting from the f and m objects, to guarantee that events are indeed called at the right time?

Your instinct is completely correct. It isn't, and it can't. This is (I claim) a long-standing API bug in the `node-imap` library. I have taken to calling it the "live grenade anti-pattern".

There is a standard way to use `EventEmitter`s like this in an API. You get the object, call a bunch of `.on(...)` or whatever, then call some other function to tell it you're ready. (Like pulling the pin of the grenade.)

What `node-imap` instead does, all over the place, is that it *pulls the pin right before handing you the grenade*. It effectively calls the "ready for events" method on the object right before returning it. (In practice I expect there is not such a method, and something more complex is happening internally.)

What this means is, everything will work fine as long as you call `.on(...)` immediately when receiving the object.

> events are not queued anywhere

This is *almost* true. There's no such queue within `EventEmitter`. But within the JS runtime itself, there are event queues: the "task queue" and the "microtask queue". What's actually happening here is that, somewhere inside `node-imap` or `EventEmitter`, there is some task or microtask getting queued that will ultimately call your handler. But Javascript is effectively single-threaded. So even though some code is *ready* to call your handlers *before* you call `.on(...)`, it happens that (essentially by luck) they don't get called until after you attach them.

The upshot of this is: If you call `await` anywhere in between receiving the object and calling `.on(...)`, or if you try to "hang on" to the object and call `.on(...)` later when you're ready for it, you will start mysteriously losing events.

> OK I am 100% confused about this matter. I am obviously missing something basic and crucial, and I am not even able to ask the right questions because of this...! (Apologies)

In fact your confusion is correct, and your observation is very astute. It took me a lot of time debugging missed events to notice this problem with the library's API.